# How to scroll to an element when a button is clicked and also make it hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Might be a duplicate but I cant seem to find the right answer.

I have a button, and when I press it, I want it to scroll to the li item that has an ID of '#li-1', and also have it hovered. I know my code is wrong but not really sure how to fix it (new to jquery). So how do I achieve the desired results?

Here's a jsfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/orb1vw28/7/

Thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('body').scrollTo('#li-1', 200);
        $("#li-1").toggleClass("hov");
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have some problems in your code, but i made some minor changes and managed it to work.

JSfiddle wans't working for me, so i made you a pen.

http://codepen.io/filipemerker/pen/jbvxyY

The thing is that you need to pass a numeric value to "scrollTo", not a selector. I just calculated the difference between the parent scrolltop minus the LI element scrolltop. I also added an animation for you. Check it out.

```
$('#event-list').stop().animate({scrollTop:location}, '200', 'linear');
```

Comment: Try clicking the button multiple times, you'll see it doesn't work correctly. @billybobjones

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the correct target position – the one which you scroll to – with [the `getScrollTargetPosition()` function in this gist](https://gist.github.com/hashchange/c368ce9c642c1a70edda) (heavily commented, so no need to explain it here).

Based on that and the [jQuery.scrollable plugin](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.scrollable) – which solves [cross-browser issues](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.scrollable#why) as well as a bunch of [scroll-related usability problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32046714/508355) –, you'd end up with this code:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( ".button" ).click( function ( event ) {

        var $window = $( window ),
            $scrollContainer = $( "#event-list" ),
            $target = $( "#li-1" ),
            targetPosition = getScrollTargetPosition ( $target, $window );

        event.preventDefault();

        $scrollContainer.scrollTo( targetPosition, {
            complete: function () {
                $target.toggleClass( "hov" );
            }
        } );

    } );
} );
```

To see it in action, check it out in JSBin ([result](http://jsbin.com/foxoci/1), [source](http://jsbin.com/foxoci/1/edit?html,css,js,output)).

Comment: This definitely doesn't need a bunch of extra code. Best to not push your plugin on *anything* that comes near. But it you think you must anyway, it would be better suited as a comment.

Comment: @Shikkediel I'd actually ask you to change your tone a bit, it comes across as rather derogatory. That aside, doing it without "a bunch of extra code" comes at a cost: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32046714/508355 . There's a trade-off between UX and code size here. You emphasize code size? Fair enough. But it's certainly not the only way to approach this.

Comment: Not changing my tone, sorry. Speaking my mind as is in the spirit of the forum. This question can have a very basic answer and you've been posting your plugin several times lately on similar ones. Under some circumstances it might be suited but I don't think it is in this case. And it really is quite bloated.